# Identifying geographic coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system, gabon

I'm looking at the following map and I can't figure out what kind of coordinate system is being used. This isn't lat/long. I assume once I know which coordinate system it is, I can easily search for a converter online.

As one can see, the coordinates are in the range of 784600N to 786000 N and 295800E to 297400E.

Any ideas?

[image]

The area in question is Gabon. Around the lat/long coordinates of  1.69°S, 13.41°E

Comment: Can you tell us something about the area where this map section is located? The text seems to be french so maybe somewhere in France?

Comment: Should be Kamerun or somewhere in Africa, thus UTM30 to 33N.

Comment: Went through all possible places in South America and Africa, I got no idea where it might be, could be Guyana, but Google-images do not fit (there seems to be a mine in the map). Could be any UTN from 18N to 21N or from 29N to 39N.

Comment: Some thoughts: We're talking meters as units, thus the - presumable - hole in the southern middle should be 400 m in diameter, quite large. The purple polygon to the east should be the deposition area for the dirt from the mine. The basemap shows hills, if not small mountains. Still, without a rough idea in which country this is, it's quite a hassle to find it.

Comment: Sorry about that. Question edited to include place now. It's actually Gabon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's UTM zone 33S (probably WGS84) - it's just that the '9' is cropped off of the northings on the left side of the image.

[image]